# Git: How to make a multiple commit revertible?

Tags: git, revert

I usually try to `squash` all commits that belong to the same feature addition on one commit. One of the reasons of doing this is to make easy to me (and my team) to `revert` my feature quickly and cleanly if necessary.

But this prevents me to divide the new additions in multiple commits when it has more sense for creating a coherent git history.

How can I add 2 commits to my history but make them revertible in one shot?

I was thinking that the `merge` commits may have some use here but I don't know how.

Comment: Why does squashing make reverting "clean" and "easy"?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass range to `git revert`. For example:

```
git revert commit1..commit2
```

Would insert N revert commits, each for the each commit in `commit1..commit2` range. It's a „one shot” command that will introduce several revert commits.